# Apply CSS Style to child elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to apply styles only to the table inside the DIV with a particular class:

Note: I'd rather use a css-selector for children elements.

Why does the #1 works and #2 doesn't?

1:

```
div.test th, div.test td, div.test caption {padding:40px 100px 40px 50px;}
```

2:

```
div.test th, td, caption {padding:40px 100px 40px 50px;}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div.test > th, td, caption {padding:40px 100px 40px 50px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <table border="2">
                <tr><td>some</td></tr>
                <tr><td>data</td></tr>
                <tr><td>here</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="test">
            <table  border="2">
                <tr><td>some</td></tr>
                <tr><td>data</td></tr>
                <tr><td>here</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't forget that the >, + and [ ] selectors are unavailable for IE6 and under.

Answer (score 390, accepted):

This code "`div.test th, td, caption {padding:40px 100px 40px 50px;}`" applies a rule to all `th` elements which are contained by a `div` element with a class named `test`, in addition to **all** `td` elements and **all** `caption` elements.

It is not the same as "all `td`, `th` and `caption` elements which are contained by a `div` element with a class of `test`".  To accomplish that you need to change your selectors:

'`>`' isn't fully supported by some older browsers (I'm looking at you, Internet Explorer).

```
div.test th,
div.test td,
div.test caption {
    padding: 40px 100px 40px 50px;
}
```

Comment: is there any way around writing div.test 3 times over?

Comment: @rm Nope. There's no nesting of rules or 'with' type grouping

Comment: @romanm There is way around writing 'div.test' 3 times over! look into using sass or less frameworks for writing css files! :)

Comment: @romanm  - see my answer, using a * to target all children to prevent repeating, or using .class > * for all direct children. Its not hard.

Comment: The hint about not being supported in IE was very helpful, I was trying to make some CSS work for DTCoreText on iOS but it wasn't working, their parser is worse than IE.

Comment: @romanm: there is, now (finally!) either using `:is()`, `where()`, or CSS nesting ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/b8Lcp3vg/)).

Answer (score 155):

```
.test * {padding: 40px 100px 40px 50px;}
```

Comment: Note that, * here means that you cannot override it with any other more specific rule because `.test *` would be the most specific rule for every child element. In other words, keep in mind that whatever you put inside `.test *` cannot be overridden by any more specific css rule because `test *` is the most specific rule.

Answer (score 102):

The `>` [selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) matches direct children only, not descendants.

You want

```
div.test th, td, caption {}
```

or more likely

```
div.test th, div.test td, div.test caption {}
```

Edit:

The first one says

```
  div.test th, /* any <th> underneath a <div class="test"> */
  td,          /* or any <td> anywhere at all */
  caption      /* or any <caption> */
```

Whereas the second says

```
  div.test th,     /* any <th> underneath a <div class="test"> */
  div.test td,     /* or any <td> underneath a <div class="test"> */
  div.test caption /* or any <caption> underneath a <div class="test">  */
```

In your original the `div.test > th` says `any <th> which is a **direct** child of <div class="test">`, which means it will match `<div class="test"><th>this</th></div>` but won't match `<div class="test"><table><th>this</th></table></div>`

Comment: fwiw, because the td and caption in that selector are "dumb" - they'll match any given th/caption without regard for div.test. That kind of blind targetting is rarely what you want in CSS for anything but the most general styles.

Comment: @annakata: that's a part of css framework, i'm trying to apply it locally

Answer (score 13):

If you want to add style in all child and no specification for html tag then use it.

Parent tag `div.parent`

child tag inside the div.parent like `<a>`, `<input>`, `<label>` etc.

code : `div.parent * {color: #045123!important;}`

You can also remove important, its not required

Answer (score 10):

This code can do the trick as well, using the SCSS syntax

```
.parent {
  & > * {
    margin-right: 15px;
    &:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is some code that I recently wrote.  I think that it provides a basic explanation of combining class/ID names with pseudoclasses.

```css
.content {
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px grey;
  margin: 30px auto 20px auto;
  /*height:200px;*/

}
p.red {
  color: red;
}
p.blue {
  color: blue;
}
p#orange {
  color: orange;
}
p#green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Class practice</title>
  <link href="wrench_favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <p id="orange">orange</p>
    <p id="green">green</p>
    <p class="red">red</p>
    <p class="blue">blue</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: CSS doesn't allow single line comments such as `//`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656546/why-dont-we-have-a-comment-in-css

Answer (score 6):

```
div.test td, div.test caption, div.test th
```

works for me.

The child selector > does not work in IE6.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know this:

```
div[class=yourclass] table {  your style here; }
```

or in your case even this:

```
div.yourclass table { your style here; }
```

(but this will work for elements with `yourclass` that might not be `div`s) will affect only tables inside `yourclass`. And, as Ken says, the > is not supported everywhere (and `div[class=yourclass]` too, so use the point notation for classes).