# Angular 5 Custom CSS

Tags: css, angular, angular5, carousel, primeng

Hey guys so im struggling to figure out how to add custom styles to elements for different pages
If i add the styles to the global css it works. 
For example i use ui-carousel on three different pages and i need them to look different on each, so global wont work for me in this case
If i put a div class in my indiviudal css pages it works fine as i can name the class.

```
<h3 style="margin-left: 20px;">Fotos</h3>
<p-carousel numVisible="4"
        [value]="_photos">
            <ng-template let-p pTemplate="p">
                <p>
                    <img style="    width: 100%;
                    padding: 4px;
                    /* margin: auto; */
                    border: 1px solid #ddd;"
                         [src]="p.photo">
                </p>
            </ng-template>
   </p-carousel>
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us understand your query first -

### You want to change the css styling of element or component in different places.

For this you following options -

### `@Input` inline css

If you have just few properties you want to update then you can opt for inline css.

### `@Input` Style Class

If you have set of themes that you want to apply on the component, then you can go with the CSS Class option as `@Input`

There are some more advance option like `Dynamic Template` but I don't think you need that.

### Overwrite CSS

To overwrite css you can use `:host` or `:host ::ng-deep`

Examples :

```
:host >>> .ui-dropdown-item {...}
```

or

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-dropdown-item {...}
```

You can see the demo in action here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wz8iq4

Comment: So i want to have each component to have its own css file. i have this linked in the  ts file. so lets say x.css and y.css in separate folders for x and y components. when i put styles in each css for divs and paragraphs it works, when i put elements like dropdown menus css it doesnt work.

Comment: I had updated the answer with **Overwrite CSS** option.

Comment: sorry for the late reply buddy. :host>>> did the trick. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: I just ran into another problem. :host doesnt work with scss is there a similar feature i have looked but cant find one

Comment: try escaping `\:host`

Answer (score 1):

You can have style-sheet corresponding to each component you create. Specify which stylesheet you want to use for a component while declaring the component:
e.g.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'your-component-selector',
    templateUrl: './your-component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./your-component.css']
})
```

You can have multiple stylesheets for a component using the `styleUrls` array.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I already have that buddy, like i can modify divs, paragraphs etc. Its for elements like 
.ui-carousel {
  position: relative !important;
  padding: 0.683rem !important;
  border: none !important;
  background: white !important;
}

which i can edit in global but not in the custom css pages which i have definedd for each component

Comment: You can also make use of @Input property on your reusable( child) component and provide the value for that in your parent component.

Comment: if the element is not in the parent component, you have to specify the style in the CSS for the child component.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to explain your question a little bit if @alokstar's answer is not what you need, because that is how I would do it as well.

If you have a CSS file for each component, plus the global one, and you specify which stylesheet you want to use in which component, there wouldn't be a problem.

`p-carousel {
   <some css styling>;
 }`

I think this article [link](https://medium.com/@davembush/adding-css-and-javascript-to-an-angular-cli-project-2b843a8283f3) explains it pretty well too.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link
[Apply CSS Style to child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632100/apply-css-style-to-child-elements)

Possible solution would be to apply a custom class name to each instance on a div wrapper or the element itself. You may also need to apply ::ng-deep but ultimately you need some sort of identifier to make them a unique 1:1 to the css you want to apply.

```
<p-carousel class="classInstance1 " numVisible="4"

p-carousel.classInstance1 .ui-carousel { 
    position: relative !important; 
    padding: 0.683rem !important; 
    border: none !important; 
    background: white !important; 
} 

p-carousel.classInstance2 .ui-carousel { 
    position: relative !important; 
    padding: 0.683rem !important; 
    border: none !important; 
    background: green !important; 
}
```