# Using css for styling a dynamic menu

Tags: php, html, css

I have this code for a dynamic menu using php:

***menu.php:***

```
<?php
    // Get current page file name
    $page = basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
?>
<?php include "templates/header.php"; ?>
<?php include "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

**templates/header.php:**

```
    <h1>A Library</h1>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php" <?php if ($page == "index.php") echo 'class="current"' ?>>Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="resume.php" <?php if ($page == "resume.php") echo 'class="current"' ?>>Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="photography.php" <?php if ($page == "photography.php") echo 'class="current"' ?>>Photography</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php" <?php if ($page == "about.php") echo 'class="current"' ?>>About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php" <?php if ($page == "contact.php") echo 'class="current"' ?>>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**templates/footer.php:**

```
</body>
</html>
```

**menu.php and file templates are in the same directory**

This code creates a simple and small sized menu.How could i make this a bit better usng css?

I wrote this css code but i have no idea how to connect it with the menu:

```
#navigation ul li a.current {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

Comment: [https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) should help.

Comment: You include it in a CSS file or a `<style>` tag. What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply CSS Style to child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632100/apply-css-style-to-child-elements)

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple ways to include CSS, in your case the simplest way would be to create a lets say style.css and include it in your main template inside the  tags: `<link href=/path/to/yourcss/style.css rel=stylesheet type='text/css'>` this way it will affect all of your dynamically included CSS and it should be class locked for interchangeable components.
Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ... other meta tags
        <link href=/path/to/yourcss/style.css rel=stylesheet type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        your php includes for content
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: So, this goes inside the header or the menu file?

Comment: this would go above your header and your menu (that is unless your `<head>` tag is inside your header.php. I have updated my answer with the correct structure

Comment: I did as you said but still it wont work.After going to dev options in chrome isaw that it chose this path for the css file:http://localhost/php-beginner-crud-level-1/css/style.css however there is no localhost folder.If i use the whole path instead of css/style.css it still puts the localhost infront.Any idea about how could this be fixed?

Comment: hi, `localhost` is not a directory, it your host name (in a real environment ir would be `www.some_domain.com` but on your local machine it just refferences to itself (typically your webserver that is running on port 80). your actual path seems to be `php-beginner-crud-level-1/css/style.css` which has to be relative to your index.php file.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `<link>` Tag to include css file with `html / php`

```
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='CSS/main.css'>
</head>
```

Comment: Sorry for downvote, but you can not put link inside style. Whatever is inside style tags has to be literal css

Comment: sorry it should be head.