# How do I select/work with the child of an element. Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a header in my html that has two different classes. Depending on when I scroll down it changes. IN CSS u select descendent with space. In my case `.navbar .menu-toggler` and `.nav_sticky .menu-toggler`. I succeded to select `.navbar` via `var h = document.getElementsByClassName(id3)[0];` (id3 being "navbar") but i want to change the style of `.menu-toggler` And i can't write directly `.menu-toggler` because i need it when it's withing the class of `.navbar`   .I over complicated the explanation but I hope somebody can help

oH and how can i add a class and remove a class to an element

Comment: Have you tried css selectors such as ">" (or just look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632100/apply-css-style-to-child-elements))?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Create yourself an answer instead or accept one of the existing answers.

Comment: You can add or remove classes using element.classList.add('classToBeAdded') and element.classList.remove('classToBeRemoved')

Comment: You've tagged the question "jquery". The jQuery way of adding/removing classes is with the `addClass` and `removeClass` methods. For example: `$('#my-element-id').removeClass('a-class')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use document.querySelector to access the toggler.

```
var menuToggler = document.querySelector(".navbar.menu-toggler");
```

You'll get the item which has .navbar and .menu-toggler inside it's classList.

I don't thing accessing children by indexes is a good practice. If your HTML document gets updated, your index might point to another DOM element.

Check this answer for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/59406548/9517443

Comment: seems like a really good answer although it doesn't resolve my problem.. I have `<button class="menu-toggler" onclick="toggle_visibility('menu','body-remake','navbar')">` and `.navbar .menu-toggler{
 background:none;
 width: 35px;
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
 z-index: 999;
 position:absolute;
 left:240px;
 top:21px;
}`.

Comment: function `toggle_visibility(id3) {
          var menuToggler = document.querySelector(".navbar.menu-toggler");
          if(e.style.left == '0px'){   //e is header// deleted that part
     
            menuToggler.style.left = '240px';
          }    
          else{
            menuToggler.style.left = '15px';
        }`  Basically i want the button to move itself to the left

Comment: I think I got it. You have something with class ".navbar" which contains a button with class ".menu-toggler". In this case you can use the following snippet: `button = document.querySelector('.navbar').querySelector('.menu-toggler');` Give it  a try.