# Applying CSS to child element

Tags: html, css

I would like to set the text color to "White" for all the list items.

Which CSS rules could I use to style them?

```html
<span class="helptext">
  <ul>
    <li>Your password can’t be too similar to your other personal information.</li>
    <li>Your password must contain at least 8 characters.</li>
    <li>Your password can’t be a commonly used password.</li>
    <li>Your password can’t be entirely numeric.</li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply CSS Style to child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632100/apply-css-style-to-child-elements)

Comment: scan.helptext ul,
li {
    color: white;
} This helped change the colors. thanks

Comment: Don't depend on error recovery. [Write valid HTML](https://validator.w3.org/). `ul` elements cannot be descendants of `span` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the lines of code like this
Imagine the li tag is your friend and you want it to come out to play, you'd have to go the house(container) element, talk to the ul tag being the parent element and then finally seeing your friend the li tag being the child element
So to access the li element, you have to enter the house, talk to the parent who will then let you see your friend li
so it'll be written as;

```
.helptext ul li{
   color: white;
 }
```